# Oracle lock table with select statement

Tags: oracle, locking

with oracle 11g express, I do in 1st instance

```
LOCK TABLE mytab IN EXCLUSIVE MODE
```

then, I open a 2nd instance and I run

```
INSERT INTO mytable ...
```

It hangs, sounds cool,
but a simple "SELECT * from mytable..." will not !?

Why ?
What is the correct way to "hang until" with the SELECT ?

** update **
Ok, I've seen this
[Exclusive table (read) lock on Oracle 10g?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487596/exclusive-table-read-lock-on-oracle-10g)

So, my case is "lost" :) ?

Comment: You can't block read access to a table in Oracle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal ...

In Oracle documentation, on EXCLUSIVE MODE, you can read

> EXCLUSIVE permits queries on the locked table but prohibits any other
>   activity on it.

Answer (score 1):

once you have put on the table lock in a separate session, if you want to be blocked on select, you can do a `select ... for update`, that will be blocked (it will wait until the lock is released)  You can also do a `select ... for update nowait`, that will come back immediately if it can't get a lock, instead of waiting

Comment: your solution will not lock records for SELECT in another session ! SELECT FOR UPDATE will only block UPDATE/DELETE/SELECT FOR UPDATE in any other sessions, but not a simple SELECT.